# Regex only matched part in matches

Tags: regex, c++11

I am expecting to get only the matched part of a line. my expression looks like :

```
std::wstring strPatternDat = L"DECL\\s+E6POS\\s+X[A-Za-z0-9]+=\\{X\\s-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,Y\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,Z\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,A\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,B\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,C\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)"
```

Line I am searching on :

```
DECL E6POS XB1={X 152.115494,Y -1553.65002,Z 1255.94604,A 162.798798,B -3.58411908,C -176.614395,S 6,T 50,E1 -4949.979,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0}
```

Finding match as :

```
    if (regex_match(line, matchesDat, expressionDat))
    {
        TRACE("Match found");
    }
```

In the matched data matchesDat i am getting full matched line.
But i am expecting only the matched part

Getting :

```
DECL E6POS XB1={X 152.115494,Y -1553.65002,Z 1255.94604,A 162.798798,B -3.58411908,C -176.614395,S 6,T 50,E1 -4949.979,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0}
```

Expecting :

```
DECL E6POS XB1={X 152.115494,Y -1553.65002,Z 1255.94604,A 162.798798,B -3.58411908,C -176.614395,
```

How can i get only matched part not the full line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `regex_search` and then get the matched value as the result, not the whole string:

```
std::wstring expressionDat = L"DECL\\s+E6POS\\s+X[A-Za-z0-9]+=\\{X\\s-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,Y\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,Z\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,A\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,B\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)+,C\\s-?-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)";
std::wstring line(L"DECL E6POS XB1={X 152.115494,Y -1553.65002,Z 1255.94604,A 162.798798,B -3.58411908,C -176.614395,S 6,T 50,E1 -4949.979,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0}");
wsmatch matchesDat;
if (std::regex_search(line, matchesDat, wregex(expressionDat)))
{
    std::wcout << L"Match found: " + matchesDat.str() << "\nSuffix: " << matchesDat.suffix().str();
}
```

[image]

The `matchesDat.suffix()` will output the rest of the string after the match.

Comment: the matchesDat contains all the matched part i got that. this match has first and second in matchesDat[0]. the first is the matched part and second is the not matched part. I need the not matched part in my case. How can i get it as wstring?

Comment: Do you mean you need to get `,S 6,T 50,E1 -4949.979,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0}`? Use `regex_replace` then replacing with an empty string. However, that sounds like a new question.

Comment: yes it's like a new question. agreed. in debug i can see the ",S 6,T 50,E1 -4949.979,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0}" in matchesDat[0].second. But can't use it as wstring. Please suggest.
Your reply is perfectly ok. Just i am not sure how can i get the second value.

Comment: Perhaps, `matchesDat.suffix().str()`? Replace the std::wcout line with `std::wcout << L"Match found: " + matchesDat.str() << "\nSuffix: " << matchesDat.suffix().str();`